# Designing responsive UI using WPF databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

I am new to WPF.  I am trying to understand MVVM pattern using WPF binding. I have below 2 classes

1. MainWindow.xamal
2. ViewModel

   I have three controls

   1. textbox which displays 'Name' property of ViewModel
   2. textbox which displays 'Status' dependency property of ViewModel
   3. Button which invokes'Execute' method of 'ViewModel' class.

   Now, Execute() method is bit bulky so I have created a delegate and invoke it asynchronously.  But still my UI is blocking and its not updating values of 'Status' dependency property

Refer to below classes.

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace bindingDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

            ///Set data context property of main windows.
            mw.DataContext = vm;
            mw.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="bindingDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"   Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,26,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,127,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Status}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,55,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
    namespace bindingDemo
{
    public class ViewModel : DependencyObject , ICommand
    {
        public string Status
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Status.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(ViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata("In Progress..."));       

        private ICommand _command = null;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Name = "Default Name";
        }


        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {            
            Action a = new Action(() =>
            {
                ///While this code is being executed, UI gets blocked.
                Console.WriteLine(Name);
                Name = "OK";
                Status = "Connecting to database....";
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Status = "Connected to database....";
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Status = "Performing validations....";
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Status = "Data saved.";

            });

            /// Even if I have invoked operation asynchronously, UI is not getting updated
            /// UI is freezing for 6 seconds and can directly see last 'Status' message on UI
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(a, null);            
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Regards,
Hemant

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: NotifyPropertyChanged, take a look into that, this tell the UI that something in the background has changed.

Comment: @djerry As per my understanding DependencyProperty is also capable of notifying UI that something has changed in background.  Infact, I can see last status i.e. 'Data saved.' on UI but because it seems to be a blocking call for UI thread its not updating/reflecting other status messages.  Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: Make sure your `PropertyChanged` notification runs on UI thread. Try assigning the status on UI thread.

Comment: @Mathew How can I pull instance of UI thread in ViewModel?  In winform we were used to do something like, control.InvokeRequired == true then control.BeginInvoke(...),  but here all my data is in ViewModel. So how do I tackle with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things here:

1. `DependencyProperty` is for... well, classes with dependency properties. For view models, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `DependencyObject` ties your inheritance now and it's not its intended usage.
2. You're invoking an action on a `Dispatcher`, and `Dispatcher` should be used to run a function on a dispatcher-thread, which in this case will be the UI thread. No wonder it gets blocked, you're calling a method on a UI thread. `Dispatcher` is useful if you want to change the UI-bound values (e.g. report some kind of progress) from the background task. You have to separate your logic, do the processing in background, then report the result.

So, that being said, your `Execute` should probably look like this (using C# 5):

```
private async Task DoStuff()
{
     await Task.Delay(5000);
    //or drop the async modifier and 'return Task.Delay(5000);'
}

public async void Execute(object parameter)
{
    await DoStuff();
    //Add some checks if it really was 'OK', catch exceptions etc
    Name = "OK";
}
```

With C# 4 (untested):

```
private Task DoStuff()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
   DoStuff().ContinueWith(result => Name = "OK", TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
   //Same as above, probably should specify appropriate TaskOptions to run the continuation
   //only when the task was completed successfully.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A ViewModel normally doesn't contain dependency properties. To be able to update the UI via data binding, it has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
Try implementing your ViewModel like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _status;

    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            if(_status == value)
                return;
            _status = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
            handler(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Implementing `ICommand` on your view model seems rather odd, too.